# How do variables get defined when calling C++ code from a WPF application?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I have a DLL in C++ with a funcion like the following:

LesMes.hpp

```
bool Sing_For_Me(CInstructment accompaniedBy, string song, string singer);
```

Meanwhile in my WPF app I was going to use the interop layer:

```
[ DllImport( "musicals.dll", EntryPoint="Sing_For_Me", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi )]
public static extern bool SingForMe(???????, string note, string singer);
```

How do I reference a *CInstrument* in the WPF code?

There seem to be lots of examples of strings being used, can you only use certain pre defined datatypes or something?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't anything for classes. You should make a C++\CLI dll project and there you can wrap `CInstrument` into a .NET class and then use that in WPF. See [this article for more info](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes#A8)

Comment: Awesome - if you have the time then please feel free to put this as an answer so I can upvote and accept it

Comment: I added my answer and elaborated on it so it's helpful to anyone else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any direct P/Invoke sort of way for C++ classes, but this is why C++\CLI was made.

You should make a C++\CLI Class project and there you can wrap `CInstrument` into a .NET class and then use that in WPF.

See this [codeproject article for more info](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes#A8)

Native C++ code just works with C++\CLI, there's something called IJW (it just works). Also see [this article for more](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10020/Using-managed-code-in-an-unmanaged-application).

You need to add a new project. Choose:

> Other Languages > Visual C++ > CLR > Class Library

[image]

Your code would look like this:

```
//native C++ CInstrument
//cinstrument.cpp
class CInstrument
{
 ..
}

//this is a CLR class
//Compatible with C#/VB.NET
//cinstrumentwrapper.cpp
ref class CInstumentWrapper
{
 private:
 CInstrument* _instrument;//delegate to the native C++ class
}
```

Comment: Can I call the CLR library from HTML5 as well as from WPF or does that require an addition step?

Comment: @Stefan Not sure exactly what you mean when you say _call from html5`. Html lies outside the .NET boundary, so this could result in a number of complicated steps. A simple approach though would be expose the functionality as a `WebService`, then you could javascript to make ajax calls to it from your html.

Answer (score 1):

How is CInstructment defined?
If it is a struct you can marshal that very easy. Create a new struct apply StructLayout(Sequential) as Attribute (see System.Runtime.InteropServices) and after just pass it to your interop. And why do you have as return type IntPtr for a bool?

You can also find more intormation here
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/02/18/marshalling-complicated-structures-using-pinvoke.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Sometimes they are structs and sometimes they are classes (there are various functions required for a musical!), is there a similar function availble for classes?  Good catch on the return type,I have editted it now.

Comment: I would say if you are using classes it can get a bit more complicated. In theory it should work but it can get very very tricky. So if I would be you... I would create structs to pass data between c++ and c# because just take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class